# Read whole file or byte(s) at a time

Tags: c#

I'm writing a serial interface to send a file to a FPGA project I’ve developed over a serial interface.

The program should send a single packet (of 16 bytes) to the FPGA and then upon a receipt confirmation the program should then send the next packet.

My question is:

When reading the file, is it practice to read the whole file into memory/ a byte array?

Or shall the program only read 16 bytes from the file at a time and read the next 16 bytes when it needs to send the next packet?

Thanks in Advance,
Mike

Comment: How big is the file? (kinda impacts the answer...)

Comment: You need to be more specific. What's your memory on your FPGA. What's your standard file size?  Are there other things going on in the system?

Comment: Hi all, sorry - I should have stated. The files will be at most 50KB.

Comment: Just the program will be running on a 3GB i5 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't ever *need* more than 16 bytes at a time, the simplest code would be the code that reads 16 bytes at a time, uses them, and then reads 16 more.

If you try to read the whole file at once, you'll have to add extra complexity -- you'll need to add buffering code and end-of-array bounds checking. You don't need any of that. Keep it simple; read what you need, use it, then read more.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go for the 16 bytes at a time approach.

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution is to read 16 bytes (or however many you need to process) at a time.

If the file is very large, reading in the whole file will probably perform worse, and if extremely large may cause an `OutOfMemoryException`.

If the file is relatively small, you probably won't notice much difference between the two techniques.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go for the 16 bytes at a time approach.